# Clang build an executrion file in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, clang++

I've been searching whole internet but I can't find the solution for building my c++ project with clang compiler. I'm new to all this stuff and sorry for misunderstanding.
I have default `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

I can compile and this is what I've got compiled, 3 files:

[image]

I need to create executable somehow...
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) (which is for MinGW but it's exactly the same for Clang for Windows), you need to explicitly add the `.exe` suffix to your output file.

So your "executable" file is the one named `main`, without any suffix or "extension".

You need to change your `tasks.json` file to add the `.exe` suffix:

```
"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
# Note the suffix here -------------------^^^^
```

Comment: That was so simple. Thanks.

Comment: My Clang does add .exe automatically (Ubuntu, when cross-compiling with MinGW libs), and so does GCC (from MSYS2). Perhaps it's disabled when Clang operates in MSVC-compatible mode?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes that's what I remember as well. Unfortunately the documentation I've seen doesn't mention it, the `.exe` suffix is only added in examples of `tasks.json`.